# According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute verb does not accept any expressions

Tags: java, jstl

I have the following index page:

```
<form action ="home.jsp">
  Insert any v1 form : <input type ="text" name="v1"/>
  <input type ="submit" value="click"/>
</form>
```

and also home.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="WEB-INF/mytag.tld" prefix="mak"%>
<mak:you verb="${param.v1}"></mak:you>
```

I am getting this error

> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute verb
>   does not accept any expressions

can anyone help?

Answer (score 21):

Go to `verb` attribute definition in `mytag.tld` and enable expression support:

```
 <attribute>
     <name>verb</name>
     <required>true</required>
     <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
 </attribute>
```

Comment: I have <mak:you verb="#{param.v1}"></mak:you> (working in jsf1.0) but this expression not working in JSF1.2. Do i have to change # to $?

Comment: can you please elaborate more, like why this is solution ?

Comment: Not sure what to add here. Expressions are disallowed by default in tag attribute values. By adding `<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>` one explicitly requires expression evaluation for tag attributes.